# Can a DFS share be used for Folder Redirection?

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-server-2008, dfs

Can a DFS share be used for Folder Redirection?

Comment: You can, but we had a weird issue that Microsoft wasn't able to resolve related to DFS, and redirected folders in a 2003 terminal server environment several years ago.  We haven't retried it in 2008.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually covered in Microsoft's FAQ for DFS. The answer is, it depends. Mostly yes but not recommended if using replication. DFS-R is made for replicating mostly static files. Users' documents change a lot and DFS-R may not be efficient at replicating the changes.

http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserversystem/dfs/dfsfaq.mspx#EWKAC  See the question, "Can I use DFS with Offline Files and redirected My Documents folders?"

Comment: I've also seen wierd conflicts between offline files conflict resolution and DFS replication. Wouldn't recommend DFS if you're also using offline files.

Comment: you don't need CSC if you just want folder redirection, but I do agree that the two together can cause conficts.

Answer (score 1):

DFS Share can aggregate multiple shares in to a single logical tree (so it all appears as one directory structure).

For Example, take:

```
\\ServerA\Share1
\\ServerB\Share2
```

And make:

```
\\example.com\DFS
    \Share1
    \Share2
```

They can also be the target of client folder redirection.

And they can do a whole lot more...

Comment: Not sure how multiple shares in a target relates.  But I agree it does work.  If with just a single target DFS is useful to make it so your configuration isn't hard coded to a specific server name.

Answer (score 0):

if you have multiple sites dfs and multiple targets folder redirection can cause issues if the sites are not done correctly.